# How to iterate over a specific range of std::set/std::multiset?

Tags: c++, stl, associative-array

For an  std::set like `std::set<std::string> set={ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff" };`
how to iterate over a specific range [a, b] of this set without tracking of extra indexes?

Something like this:

```
for(auto it = set.begin(); it!=set.begin()+b; ++it)
   std::cout << *it << " ";
```

Or like this:

```
for(auto it = set.begin()+a; it!=set.begin()+b; ++it)
   std::cout << *it << " ";
```

where `a<=b` and `b<=set.size()`

Comment: `std::set` don't have a random access `iterator`. It has a bidirectional `iterator`. You can't do that.

Comment: What are you asking for exactly, going from range, let's say 3-5, of from all elements starting with "a" to all elements ending with "b" in the set?

Comment: @ThePhilomath I know! But it can be done using extra index in the for-loop, however I wanted to know if there is better ways to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do `set.begin()+a`, but you can do `std::advance(it, a)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
 
int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> set={ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff" };
    size_t a = 1, b = 4;
    auto it = set.begin(), it_end = set.begin();
    std::advance(it, a);
    std::advance(it_end, b);
    for(; it!= it_end; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Unfortunately you cannot do something like `auto it = std::advance(set.begin(), a);`, because `advance` gets the iterator by reference and changes it inplace.

https://ideone.com/8nRjgr

Better solution use `std::next`, thanks to @Evg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
 
int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> set={ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff" };
    size_t a = 1, b = 4;
    for(auto it = std::next(set.begin(), a), it_end = std::next(it, b-a); it != it_end; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
}
```

https://ideone.com/6wgpMZ

Comment: Take a look at `std::next`, you can do `std::next(set.begin(), a)`.

Comment: I'd prefer not to advance from begin twice, instead `auto it = set.begin(); std::advance(it, a); auto it_end = it; std::advance(it, b-a);`, or slightly more compact: `auto it = std::next(set.begin(), a), it_end = std::next(it, b-a);`. You shouldn't include the call to std::next inside the loop's condition check as it's re-evaluated every time and not cheap.

Comment: thanks, interesting to know! How about initializing the first and last as this ```auto it = std::next(set.begin(), a);  auto it_end = std::next(a, b-a)```? Or is the cost of iterators arithmetic the same as integer arithmetic?

Comment: @BoboFeugo As both iterators are of same type you could do `for(auto it = std::next(set.begin(), a), it_end = std::next(it, b-a); it != it_end; ++it)`

Comment: worth mentioning that the reason that a `set` cannot be iterated like other (sequence) containers is that it is inefficient. In principle a `std::set` could work with `for(auto it = set.begin(); it!=set.begin()+b; ++it)` but that is disabled on purpose. You are forced to think twice before

Comment: @BoboFeugo It depends on the type of iterator. For random access iterators, the costs are the same as for integer arithmetic. For others (like for `std::set::iterator`!), it is *not*! You need to follow links from node to node until you reach the desired one. For comparison, look at a linked list – same principle, but simpler to understand, as only one successor node existing.

Comment: for the same reason you should calculate the end of the range only once before the loop. Currently you are traversing the set on each iteraton to calculate the loop condition

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `slice` class, kind of like `std::span`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>
#include <string>

template <class Iter>
class slice {
 private:
  Iter _beg;
  Iter _end;

 public:
  slice(Iter beg, Iter end) noexcept 
    : _beg{beg}
    , _end{end} 
  {}

  slice(Iter beg, std::size_t sz) noexcept 
    : slice(beg, std::next(beg, sz)) 
  {}

  auto begin() const noexcept { return _beg; }
  auto end() const noexcept { return _end; }
};

int main() {
  std::set<std::string> const set{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff"};

  slice const sl(set.begin(), 3);

  for (auto const& elm : sl) std::puts(elm.c_str());
}
```

[<kbd>Godbolt</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TYjYGq)

Comment: Also interesting to know, thanks! You seem to be missing the template parameter when defining `slice const sl(set.begin(), 3)`. Or is this a c++20 feature?

Comment: @BoboFeugo This is fine for C++17 and later. It deduces the type from constructor arguments. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jvxG5n